# String.replace with verbatim string

Tags: c#, string, replace, verbatim-string

I have a string which has several occurrences of the following text, exactly as it appears:

`\\(Y/A M D/J\\`

The unclosed parenthesis is causing issues, so I thought I would remove the offending section, as I do not need that portion for my use of the larger string.

I've attempted to use the following line to remove the text, however `Line` is identical before and after running:

```
Line = Line.Replace(@"\\(Y/A M D/J\\", "");
```

I've used the verbatim string Identifier to avoid confusion with having to escape the special characters manually. Is there something special required to do a string.replace() when working with verbatim strings?

Note: The string Values I'm getting are pulled from Visual Studio's quickwatch feature, where I am inspecting `Line` and copying the value.

Comment: `Note: The string Values I'm getting are pulled from Visual Studio's quickwatch feature, where I am inspecting Line and copying the value.` QuickWatch doesn't show the string 'as is'. Click the magnifying glass at the end of the row and then `Text Visualizer` to see the **actual** value.

Comment: I stand corrected. The only thing we can say is that `Line` does not contain that string: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zIsS18

Comment: You want to use `Line = Line.Replace(@"\(Y/A M D/J\", "");`

Comment: You are using the verbatim string, and still escaping the `\\` character at the same time... the quickwatch assumes you are not using verbatim.

Comment: @NetMage, that's the answer.

Comment: mjwills and NetMage had the correct answer, VS was adding the additional backslashes to escape the existing ones in their text previewer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `\\` in the original string does not include escape characters? The following snippet works as you desire but assumes the original value, `input`, is exactly as shown. The result is `output` will contain `some more text`:

```
var input = @"\\(Y/A M D/J\\some more text";
var output = input.Replace(@"\\(Y/A M D/J\\", "");
```

[Link to .NET Fiddle to demonstrate](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6BLdKH)

Comment: Thank you for the input, The comments in the question also lead me to the correct answer, where VS was adding extra escape characters to the string.